# Does Arale appear in Dragon Ball Z?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-z

I remember Arale appearing in the episodes of Dragon Ball when Goku fights General Blue and also in a Dragon Ball movie of that time when they fight Tao Pai Pai. She also appeared recently in Dragon Ball Super and had a fight with Goku and Vegeta. But what about Dragon Ball Z?

Does Arale ever appear in Dragon Ball Z?